# SharePoint Forms

Tags: 2013

We are moving to SharePoint 2013 and need to find a form solution.  We are looking at KWizCom Forms, Nintex and Emgage.  I would like to know your recommendations and what you believe the optimal form solution would be.

Comment: That purely depends on what kind of requirements you have, if more customization then developing Webparts will be best. You will have to figure out which are pros and cons for each tool

Comment: SharePoint 2013 offers a lot of new features, no longer required for third party forms in most of the cases, you can user REST /JSOM for all custom forms and eay to develop with responsive nature

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no optimal Form solution, it all depends on:

- Your requirements
- Your capabilities
- Your requirements
- Your budget
- Your requirements

Maarten Visser did a great overview recently for Collab365

- Collab365 Video: https://collab365.conferencehosts.com/confs/Summit2016/c365summitvisser/ConfPages/SessionRoom.aspx
- Slidedeck:
  http://www.slideshare.net/mvisser/infopath-alternatives-and-the-powerapps-potential-62135010

[image]